# How to do a spatial join in QGIS with two layers with different CRS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2.18

I am trying to do a Spatial Join (Link Attributes based on location) with two shapefiles. What I want to do is determine which streets are in a certain region, or in other words are contained in that region.

I have a drawn the shapefile of regions which will be the join layer, but I have realised too late that this shapefile was not in the project CRS which is Belge lambert 72. The shapefile I have drawn as the join layer is WGS 84.

[image]

I have CRS transformation on so QGIS is actually projecting it in the right place it should be.

However, when I have tried to to change the CRS from WGS 84 to lambert 72, either it does not work, or the location changes?

I thought it would not change anything but I was wrong, as you can see in the table above all value's that are joined to the street layer are NULL.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have both files in the same CRS. The on-the-fly transformation sadly only works visually, all calculations are still depended on the raw data.

Comment: So what do I need to do, if I change the CRS it either does not work, or the location does not match.

Comment: You need to transform the file correctly, i assume you might have only set the crs-value in the properties of the layer. This way you have drawn some regions in wgs 84 but told the program the coordinates are in another system. But the coordinates are still the same and therefore not fitting. Export the region-layer with the right-click option "save as" and set the new crs there.